# How do I index through a dictionary within a dictionary?

Tags: python

I have a dictionary within a dictionary with this default structure:

```
meta_data.setdefault(date_str, {'games': 0, 'wins': 0})
```

After indexing through a spreadsheet to calculate the totals per date I get a dictionary with key,values like so:

```
'04/01/2020': {'games': 7, 'wins': 2.0}
```

I want to calculate the win ratio, and so I (think I) need to index through each date.  The calculation needs to access both key,values from the sub-dictionary.  I know this is super basic....thanks for the help.

Comment: Do you just need: `meta_data['04/01/2020']['games']`?

Comment: @theEngineeredSelf Please let me know if my answer works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like `dictionary_name["key1"]["key2"]` to access any value from the dictionary.

For example: `dictionary_name['04/01/2020']['games']`

If you want to do this as a loop:

```py
for key in dictionary_name:
    value = dictionary_name[key]
```

If you want to do a loop over a multidimensional dictionary:

```py
for key1 in dictionary_name:
    for key2 in dictionary_name[key1]:
        value = dictionary_name[key2]
```

**Coming to your specific example, I think this is what you are trying to do:**

```py
games = 0
wins = 0
for date in dictionary_name:
    games += dictionary_name[date]['games']
    wins += dictionary_name[date]['wins']
win_ratio = wins / games
win_percentage = win_ratio * 100
# from here, you can do your calculations as needed
```

I hope this helps! Comment if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

`meta_data.values()` returns a list of the dictionary values. In your case, this will be a list of dictionaries of the form `{'games': 0, 'wins': 0}`. The key is to iterate through this list of dictionaries and sum the fields you want.

You can do the iteration using a standard "C" style loop, but python prioritizes clarity and readability. Here's the pythonic (and more concise) approach:

```py
def sum_field(field: str):
   return sum(entry[field] for entry in meta_data.values())

win_ratio = sum_field('wins') / sum_field('games')
```

Comment: You're welcome @theEngineeredSelf - welcome to the world of Python, where almost anything can be done in 1 line! :) If this answer worked for you, please up-vote and select as answer :)